# How can I create a ceiling being broken?

Tags: physics

Using Blender 2.91 -
I have already learned how to use the cell fracture add-on and how to break things up, but my lack of understanding is in how to keep a pre-broken section of ceiling from falling or breaking up until it is struck by an object from above. I haven't figured out the animation/physics to keep the broken section "stuck" to the ceiling and being smashed from above. The collision object falls as it should, but so does the ceiling section . . . I am trying to figure out how to keep it in place before being hit and shattered. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Keyframe animated trait on frame 0.  Keyframe it off on the frame that the smasher touches it.